# R packageR2BayesX multi state model

Tags: r, markov-chains

Hello I would like to know how to fit a multi-state model in R package R2BayesX?

I believe you have to use the `bayesx` function. How do I correctly do so?
My data frame consists of variables such as remission, time from diagnosis, height, age, of course remission/not remission would be my states (1/0).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi state models in R2BayesX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862790/multi-state-models-in-r2bayesx)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you. Moreover, your question seem to be more about statistics than about programming. You might want to have a look at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)